# Odoo browse return wrong value on first call

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I have a custom model with an init view for `_auto = False`
when I access the list view I got wrong data in a Many2one field `analytic_line_type_id` !
Debugging results:

```
 > /odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py(3247)_read_format()
-> for record, vals in data:
(Pdb) record[name], record.analytic_line_type_id,  self.env[self._name].search_read([('id','=',record.id)],['analytic_line_type_id'])[0]
(account.analytic.line.type(1,), account.analytic.line.type(1,), {'id': 9057, 'analytic_line_type_id': (15, "Temps d'assemblage atelier")})
(Pdb) record[name], record.analytic_line_type_id,  self.env[self._name].search_read([('id','=',record.id)],['analytic_line_type_id'])[0]
(account.analytic.line.type(15,), account.analytic.line.type(15,), {'id': 9057, 'analytic_line_type_id': (15, "Temps d'assemblage atelier")})
(Pdb) record[name], record.analytic_line_type_id,  self.env[self._name].search_read([('id','=',record.id)],['analytic_line_type_id'])[0]
(account.analytic.line.type(15,), account.analytic.line.type(15,), {'id': 9057, 'analytic_line_type_id': (15, "Temps d'assemblage atelier")})
```

Why record.analytic_line_type is not correct in the first call ?
As you can see the search_read value is different to direct access to the field!

Comment: without the modules involved and a way to debug it it's almost impossible to tell you why that it's happening

Comment: @aekis.dev thank you for responding, I founded the solution

Answer (score 0):

in the sql view the id may changes, I added the field on the order by of the row_number()

```
row_number() OVER ( order by analytic_line_type_id)
```